# static char array in C initialized with strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, static, char

im trying to wrap my head around a piece of code we got in our C lecture but I can't figure out what it does.

Here's the code:

```
int main() {
    static char *s[] = {"black", "white", "pink", "violet"};
    char **ptr[] = {s+3, s+2, s+1, s}, ***p; 
    p = ptr; 
    ++p; 
    printf("%s", **p+1); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The above code prints "ink", but how does it work?

Trying

```
printf("s: %c\n",*s[0]);
```

gives me `'b'`, `*s[1]` returns `'w'`, `*s[2]` returns `'p'`and so on. So `*s` basically returns the first letter of the strings it has been initialized with. Trying

```
printf("s: %c\n",**ptr[0]);
```

returns `v`, so `*s` seemingly looks like this:

```
{b,w,p,v};
```

This, however, is not confirmed by `sizeof(s)` returning 16 and not 4.

So my question is: whats going on here? Where's the rest of the characters stored?

Comment: For starters, for any array or pointer `s` and index `i`, the expression `s[i]` is exactly equal to `*(s + i)`. That also means that `s + i` is exactly equal to `&s[i]`. And don't forget that arrays naturally decays to pointer to their first elements, i.e. `ptr` will decay to `&ptr[0]`. Those two facts should help explain `ptr` and `p`. Now, with some pen and paper try to figure out the rest by drawing boxes for each array (and don't forget that the string literals are arrays as well) and using arrows for the pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are doing

```
printf("s: %c\n",*s[0])  // this prints the character 'b'
```

If you use `%s` you will get the entire string

```
printf("s: %s\n",s[0])
```

A line by line explanation of the code is below

```
static char *s[] = {"black", "white", "pink", "violet"};  
                         // Here s is an array of pointers to char. 
                         // s[0] will point to "black", s[1] will point to "white" etc.
char **ptr[] = {s+3, s+2, s+1, s}, ***p;  
                        //ptr is an array of pointer to pointer to char.  
                        // ptr[0] will be equal to s+3, i.e. &s[3].
                        // ptr[1] will be &s[2]
                        // p is a pointer to pointer to a pointer. (triple pointer)
p = ptr;                // p is set as the base addr of ptr.
++p;                    // p is incremented, i.e. it points to next element of ptr, i.e. ptr[1]
printf("%s", **p+1);    // This is equivalent to (**p) +1
                        // p = &s[2]. therefore
                        // *p = s[2]
                        // **p = *(s[2]) --> **p points to the `p` character in pink
                        // **p +1 will point to the `i` character in `pink'. That is what is printed.
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I think I got the gist, but why is `***p`a pointer to a pointer? Shouldn't it be a pointer to a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Sorry, i missed that. Corrected.

Comment: Right, got it. One more thing: `sizeof(s)` returns 16 since `*s[]` is an array of 4 pointers to char - which each has a size of 4 bytes? How come?  `s[0] = "black"`,right, which is a char array of size 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

you are using %c which will print only one character so rather you should use, %s which will print complete string from startding address until \0 is encountered.

related to sizeof(s) , it will print the size of number of elements present in your array i.e 4 pointers of size each 4 bytes each pointing to a string.